# Guzzle verify option SSL routines::unsafe legacy renegotiation disabled

Tags: php, ssl, guzzle

I've run into an ssl issue with an [external api](https://developers.kvk.nl/support/documentation/manual-tls-certificate) using a self signed tls certificate.
Guzzle [docs](https://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/request-options.html#verify) say you can provide a custom ca-bundle from disk which I tried but that results in an `SSL routines::unsafe legacy renegotiation disabled`.

Basically what i'm doing is the following:

```php
$client->request(
    'GET',
    'https://api.kvk.nl/v1/zoeken',
    ['verify' => '/var/www/html/Private_G1_chain.pem']
);
```